# Is there a way to reset the value of a MutableLiveData?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I noticed there's a `NOT_SET` value in `LiveData`. Is there a way to reset a `MutableLiveData` to this? Basically, I have a use case where I want to reset the `MutableLiveData` back to like it was never set.

Answer (score 0):

That use case sounds suspicious. I think you're doing something weird. The general practice is to create a state class and extend it and use that as your state. Here is an example in Kotlin:

```kotlin
sealed class MyUIState {
    object Loading : MyUIState()
    class Loaded(val data: String) : MyUIState()
    class Error(val error: Throwable) : MyUIState()
}
```

Then observe your state like this.

```kotlin
when(state) {
    MyUIState.Loading -> showLoadingView()
    is MyUIState.Loaded -> dataLoaded(state.data)
    is MyUIState.Error -> showError(state.error)
}
```

If you want to reset the state, just set the value back to `MyUIState.Loading`.
Does this answer your question?

Comment: thanks. yah, I understand the state class but this `LiveData` is already being used by many other classes in the project. If I were to change this from `LiveData<Boolean>` to state, it would be nearly impossible. I tried to set the livedata with `null` value. it trigged the observer and that's not what we want.

Comment: You can try changing `mData` to `NOT_SET` with reflection, but that just sounds like a bad idea. You should really consider refactoring existing code. Maybe also start using `MutableStateFlow`? In my experience it's way more powerful in bigger projects.